# html page to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to append html page to json object, and want to access the div tags by there id from json object. I am new to this and don't know want to do.

the scenario is like this:

I have a html page in which multiple div tags are there with id=page1, page 2 and so on. I want to add this page to json object and than access it page id wise in js i.e page1 page2 and so on..can anyone provide some solution to this.

I have just seen some values are entered in json object.how to append some html page or the elements to it?

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly, you are trying to store page contents in a JSON object for future use.

Saving page content is straight forward, get the `innerHTML` of the `body` tag into a variable or assign directly to your JSON object's property.

```
var body = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('body'))[0];
json.Content = body.innerHTML;
```

Getting the JSON object's property to be able to query, is a little tricky. You will need to use the DOM parser to parse it and then query it.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(json.Content, "text/html");
```

Here is a small demo:

```js
var data = '{"id":"1", "Title":"Page", "Content":""}';
var json = JSON.parse(data);

var body = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('body'))[0];
json.Content = body.innerHTML;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(json.Content, "text/html");

console.log(htmlDoc.getElementById("Page-02").innerText);
```

```html
<div id="Page-01">
  1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
<div id="Page-02">
  2. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
</div>
<div id="Page-03">
  3. Ut enim ad minim veniam
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [github](https://github.com/Jxck/html2json) project. you can use this library easily.

Comment: thanks but..how to I access particular div from that.

Comment: if you have `<div id="1" class="foo">` then its json format will be `attr: { id: '1', class: 'foo' },` into child. you can access this using you class name.